# How to you remove characters before and after a string in python?

Tags: python

How do I remove the whitespace and strip of the newline carriage return from a string? I tried:

```
a = []
for i in range(len(lines)):
     a.append(lines[i].rstrip().lstrip('\n'))
```

lines is a list of lines that was created with the readlines() function.

Comment: You haven't told us how what you tried was wrong. Did you get an error (and if so, what was the error, where is the stack trace)? Unexpected output (and if so, what was it)?

Comment: If I may suggest you, instead of looping through the `i` index, you can do `for line in lines`. Cleaner and more pythonic!

Comment: It's also worth noting Python `for` loops iterate over objects, not indices - Python isn't designed to loop by index. Instead of doing all that extra work, loop directly over the file object. You don't need to use `readlines()` to get a list (which is less memory efficient), as the file object is an iterator itself.

Comment: `'  Did gyre and gimble in the wabe:'`  That's one of the items from the list, the newline return was removed but not the whitespace at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Another thing is that it's common to build a new list by modifying elements of an iterator in Python. The easiest way to do this is a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) removes all whitespace from either side of a string, so the easiest way to do what you want is simply:

```
with open("source.txt") as file:
    a = [line.strip() for line in file]
```

The problem with your code is you are using [`str.lstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) and [`str.rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) the wrong way around - the newline is on the right, but you are trying to strip it from the left. The newline gets stripped as the `str.rstrip()` strips all whitespace from the right (including newlines), while the `str.lstrip("\n")` finds no newline character from the left and so does nothing, hence your problem.

If you need to leave trailing whitespace *except* the newline, then you would want `line.rstrip("\n").lstrip()` - swapping the arguments for the left and right strips from your original code. This would ensure no whitespace other than the newline is stripped, as it would be with the above code.

Note that I use a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) to do this - it's both more readable and efficient, and a good way to do tasks like this.

I also loop directly over the file object, as that is more efficient (the lines do not have to be loaded into memory). Note my use of the [the with statement](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4) to open files - this is a best practice in Python as it protects you from subtle bugs, and is (again) more readable

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [line.strip() for line in lines]
```

I think it's better to strip before put it into lines list